# Question where no research has been conducted at all

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, flags

I'm sure we have all seen questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712197/).

A one - two line question which shows a clear lack of even [Googling](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=Googling&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=u4r6Uvv-F8i10wWImoHwCA#q=define:Googling&rls=en&safe=off) the question.
These are often easily identified by the phase *Is it possible?* when what the user really means is:
**GIVE ME THE CODEZ**

I know that recently the flagging options have changed, however now cannot find the meta post.

What would be the most appropriate flag for a question like this, or are these kinds of questions allowed?

The flags *too-board* OR *off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.* Don't really seem to quite cover the issue with questions like these.

Also the answer to the exampled question feels to me like a comment. However it is answering the question.

Whilst I know [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143354/238300) is a little out dated and references the FAQ part of the site. Its still accepted that these types of questions should not be encouraged.

Comment: The general feedback is vote/flag to close if the question is Too Broad or Unclear or a Duplicate, not because there is no research.  If you don't think there was enough research, then downvote (that's what the tooltop says)

Comment: @psubsee2003 Was unaware of the tooltip, thanks :)

Comment: Closely related: [What happened to the "you're just lazy" close vote reason?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216491)

Comment: shouldn't you just downvote these questions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> These are often easily identified by the phase Is it possible? when what the user really means is:
>   GIVE ME THE CODEZ

You're making a pretty big assumption here. The truth is, it's not really clear *what* he wants - the question would actually be *much improved* if he described a specific problem and asked for help writing the code to solve it.

Indeed, he may just want someone to point him in the direction of the proper api or technique so that he can write the "codez" himself...

...but the point is, *we don't know!*

**When you focus on specific problems that make *answering* problematic, picking a close reason becomes trivial.** Lack of research is a reason to *down-vote* - but a question that's impossible or unnecessarily difficult to answer is always a reason to close.

Therefore, the question needs to be closed, *not* because it lacks research, but because it is unclear and overly-broad.