# Where to post my question

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are questions asking for tutorials allowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139008/are-questions-asking-for-tutorials-allowed)

I am very new to asp.net. I need someones help to find out good tutorials on visual studio 2010 **Asp.net web site** template. Where should I ask this question. Please advice me.

Comment: Programming forum. Stack Overflow is for specific programming problems, it's not for tutorials.

Comment: Nowhere really. We don't link to tutorials nor recommend books. If you have a practical problem, you can ask about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sites here are optimized for helping people get over defined hurdles as opposed to being wiki like answers listing 10 goof books or 10 good tutorials.

Just start working on something - and be careful to not post too many vague or entry-level questions. If you have spent several hours on a problem and can frame it with what you tried, and ask someone to either explain why what you are doing is broken or suggest a better approach, you should be fine to ask one or two questions a week to get a feel for if Stack Overflow is a place for your level of learning.