# Reopen Queue Failed Review Audit

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

OK I just failed a [Reopen Review Queue Audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/1579500), here's the question in mention

> I have the jar developed using the SNMP4J Agent source code. How can I
>   test run the Agent ? I would like to include a MIB file and test the
>   GET and SET methods. How can I write a test class for this? Any link
>   or tutorial will also be grateful Thanks in advance

I believe the question is *not a real question* or *not constructive* (asking for [tutorials](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139008/are-questions-asking-for-tutorials-allowed)). Further even if the question is a "border-line" and is left opened, if it **had** been closed I don't think it should be reopened.

Back when the review audits didn't count I asked if there was a way to [disagree with the systems recommendation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146790/is-there-a-way-to-disagree-with-the-review-systems-recommendation),  I think now that they count there should be some way to at least provide feedback so whatever algorithm is used to supply the review audits can be refined.

I do understand that it takes more then one failed audit to get banned, however I believe the primary purpose of the review audits are to make sure your paying attention, and I think that at least in the Reopen queue it can still use a bit of work.

Comment: The actual question is `"How can I write a test class for this?"`, not "What's a good link or tutorial to do this". The OP specifies that a link or tutorial may be nice, but it is not required and is not the core of the question. I would say the Review Audit is correct in failing you for not paying attention :)

Comment: I think asking how to write a test class is a bit to broad and would fall under *NARQ*, and at the very least doesn't merit to be reopened.

Comment: It has got 5 upvotes, so it *has* to be a good question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168366/failed-a-reopen-question-audit-sure-looks-like-not-a-real-question-to-me/168372#168372

Comment: @BoPersson I don't think the number of up-votes has any bearing on whether it is a valid question, especially for older questions (this one is from 2011).

Comment: @Jack - No, you might not ([and neither do I](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167239/how-do-we-select-audits-for-reopen-review)), but the feature designers hope it would be a good indicator. See the link in my previous comment.

Comment: @Jack: I failed a similar question on Programmers; the audits are picked partly based on their score.

Comment: @BoPersson When I first read your comment I thought that you were perhaps being slightly sarcastic (the *italics*), but I wasn't sure because of the link.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I realize that, and I noticed that even [@Shog9](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) mentioned in that same post that they are aware that the biggest weakness with the selection criteria is the score. Perhaps the score should be weighted based on the age of the post?

Answer (score 5):

It's awfully broad. At a bare minimum I would edit out

> Any link or tutorial will also be grateful Thanks in advance

Before voting to re-open. At that point what remains is a little light on specificity - I would have to know what else is going in the tag to make a final decision.

But for sure just clicking <kbd>Reopen</kbd> would not be right imo.